# Cannot render form tag using 'render' in Grails Controller

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, render

Using markup with the render is not adding the form tag.

I tried this with contentType "text/html", "txt/xml" and it does not work.

I have this in my controller:

```
 def myTest= {
    render(contentType: "text/plain") {
        div(id:"myDiv") {
            p "somess text inside the div"
            form (action:'get') {
                p "inside form"
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm getting this:

```
<div id='myDiv'><p>somess text inside the div</p><p>inside form</p></div>
```

I want this:

```
<div id='myDiv'><p>somess text inside the div</p><form><p>inside form</p></form></div>
```

Does anybody know why is not adding the form and how to add it?

Thanks,

Federico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this problem earlier and the work around was to use the builder directly

```
def test = {
    def sw = new StringWriter()
    def b = new MarkupBuilder(sw)
    b.html(contentType: "text/html") {
        div(id: "myDiv") {
            p "somess text inside the div"
            b.form(action: 'get') {
                p "inside form"
            }
        }

    }
    render sw
}
```

will render the following HTML

```
<html contentType='text/html'>
  <div id='myDiv'>
    <p>somess text inside the div</p>
    <form action='get'>
      <p>inside form</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Aaron is right, calling form on it's own is probably clashing with the g:form taglib method that is dynamically added to all controllers